# COUCHDB method not allowed

Tags: couchdb

from a couch app client form I'm sending methods POST and LINK from an html form
How do i enable these methods server side from the Futon I/F or local.ini file

the initiator is jquery-1.6.2.min.js:18 type text/plain  method LINK   or post

Comment: What is LINK? That's not a valid HTTP method

Comment: I was following this guide http://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/javascript/article.php/3471111

Answer (score 0):

LINK is not a valid HTTP method. List of HTTP methods is available [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol#Request_methods).